# Setting up NixOS with lvmcache and LUKS-on-LVM

Tags: lvm, grub, luks, nixos

I'm trying to install NixOS 19.09 on a notebook. My disk setup is a 30GB SSD and a 700GB HDD. I decided that I want to use the SSD as cache for the HDD, and also that I want the entire root partition to be encrypted.

My partition setup therefore looks like this:

- */dev/sda* - SSD

  - */dev/sda1* - boot partition, UEFI bootable flag, formatted with FAT, unencrypted
  - */dev/sda2* - to be used for the cache
- */dev/sdb* - HDD, unpartitioned, to be used as the main disk with LVM

I formatted */dev/sda1* with mkfs.fat, I set up a volume group vg that included */dev/sda2* and */dev/sdb*, and I then followed the guide that you can find in the [lvmcache manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/lvmcache.7.html). After creating a single cached volume called *hdd0*, I ran cryptsetup on it, so that I could achieve a LUKS-on-LVM scheme. The entire cached *hdd0* is encrypted with *LUKS2*.
Then I unlocked *hdd0* again using cryptsetup, mapping it to */dev/mapper/root*. I mounted */mnt* on it, created */mnt/boot* and mounted */dev/sda1* there. After that, I generated a NixOS config and basically left it at default, with the notable changes of adding *dm-cache* to *boot.initrd.kernelModules*, and setting *boot.initrd.luks.devices."root".preLVM* to *false*. Then, I ran `nixos-install` successfully and rebooted.

The system managed to successfully run GRUB, but after that failed to find the root volume. It provided an error message of:

```
device-mapper: table: 254:3: cache: Error creating cache's policy  
device-mapper: reload ioctl on (254:3) failed: Invalid argument
```

I'm assuming it has a problem with detecting the entire *hdd0*. I tried booting it from the live installation USB stick, and there you have to enable *dm-cache* using modprobe and then run

```
# lvchange -ay vg
```

to get *hdd0* to be active and visible.

Did anyone try a similar setup? How can I get it to boot automatically? Or is the setup flawed conceptually and can never work?

PS: I hope the question is detailed enough, it's my first time asking here.

Comment: Have you tried adding dm-cache to `boot.initrd.availableKernelModules`? The modules listed here are added to the initrd, making them available _before_ the root fs is mounted.

Comment: I tried, didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my conf that I got to work, today, after some headbangery:

```
boot.initrd.availableKernelModules = [ "nvme" "xhci_pci" "ahci" "ehci_pci" "usb_storage" "usbhid" "sd_mod" "sr_mod" ];
  boot.initrd.kernelModules = [ "dm-cache" "dm-cache-smq" "dm-cache-mq" "dm-cache-cleaner" ];
  boot.kernelModules = [ "kvm-amd" "dm-cache" "dm-cache-smq" "dm-persistent-data" "dm-bio-prison" "dm-clone" "dm-crypt" "dm-writecache" "dm-mirror" "dm-snapshot"];

  boot.initrd.luks.devices = {
    "decrypted" = {
      device = "/dev/mapper/vg-crypt";
      allowDiscards = true;
      preLVM = false;
    };
  };
```

The main trick was to have `"dm-cache-smq"` in modules - without it, I was getting a similar error message like what you're getting.

You'll have an ugly warning message about `cache_check` missing - to get rid of it, add this too:

```
services.lvm.boot.thin.enable = true;
```