# LVM configuration does not persist on nixos

Tags: lvm, reboot, nixos

I've been banging my head against a wall trying to get my nixos cached raid to work, to no avail. It's a LVM raid with optane caching, with the following `lsblk` output after first creation:
[image]

/dev/nvme0n1p2 is the ssd cache, while /dev/sda and /dev/sdb are the raid disks.

I generate the disk configuraion using:

```
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdb
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/nvme0n1p2
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda quad1
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb quad2
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p2 quadcache
lvs
pvcreate /dev/mapper/quad1 /dev/mapper/quad2 /dev/mapper/quadcache
pvs
vgcreate vgquad /dev/mapper/quad1 /dev/mapper/quad2 /dev/mapper/quadcache
vgs
lvcreate -n data-quad1 -l 100%FREE vgquad /dev/mapper/quad1
lvcreate -n data-quad2 -l 100%FREE vgquad /dev/mapper/quad2
lvcreate -n data-quadcache1 -L 10G vgquad /dev/mapper/quadcache
lvcreate -n data-quadcache2 -L 10G vgquad /dev/mapper/quadcache
lvconvert --type cache --cachevol data-quadcache1 --cachemode writethrough vgquad/data-quad1
lvconvert --type cache --cachevol data-quadcache2 --cachemode writethrough vgquad/data-quad2
mkfs.btrfs -m raid1 -d raid1 /dev/vgquad/data-quad1 /dev/vgquad/data-quad2
mount -t btrfs -o defaults,noatime,compress=zstd /dev/vgquad/data-quad1 /mnt/quad/
lsblk
```

I'm no expert, but the general advice for getting a hard drive configuration to persist on boot for nix is to get the drives configured, run `nixos-generate-config` and then `sudo nixos-rebuild switch`. In my case, it doesn't generate a proper config to mount all 3 disks, and when I do end up mounting them manually after reboot with `cryptsetup`, the table shown above no longer exists. I've tried manually mounting all 3 disks with something like this, to no avail:

```
boot.initrd.luks.devices = {
    [...]
    "luks-UUID" = {
      device = "/dev/disk/by-uuid/UUID";
      allowDiscards = true;
      preLVM = false;
    };
    [...]
  };
```

I'm at my wit's end here, I can't figure out what I've done wrong. Is there something I'm missing with how LVM persists on reboot in general, or is this some specific thing with LVM and nixos?

Comment: Why `preLVM = false`?

Comment: I chose that because of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/574215/setting-up-nixos-with-lvmcache-and-luks-on-lvm. However I/they could be wrong